# How to config and use multi master nodes in a Hadoop cluster?

Tags: hadoop

Could anyone please tell us how to config and use multi master nodes in a Hadoop cluster?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking multiple NameNodes, then check [HDFS high availability](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2012/03/high-availability-for-the-hadoop-distributed-file-system-hdfs/) and [HDFS federation](http://hortonworks.com/blog/an-introduction-to-hdfs-federation/). Both should be available in [2x Hadoop release](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/releases.html).

One more master in 1x Hadoop release in the JobTracker and there can be only one JobTracker in a cluster. BTW, JobTracker functionality has been split in the 2x Hadoop release. Check [this](http://www.cloudera.com/blog/2012/02/mapreduce-2-0-in-hadoop-0-23/) for more details.

There might be some other alternate options also, but depends on the requirement for having multiple masters. Is it availability, scalability or something other?